# How to convert PDF to base64 in react-native-document-picker?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, base64

I would like to convert the response of react-native-document-picker to base64 format. As a response I get the Uri of the file but unfortunately no base64.

this is my code:

````
const openDocumentFile = async () =>{
        try {
            const results = await DocumentPicker.pickMultiple({
              type: [DocumentPicker.types.pdf],
              readContent: true
            });
            for (const res of [results]) {
           
              console.log(res)
          
            };
                
          } catch (err) {
            if (DocumentPicker.isCancel(err)) {
            } else {
              throw err;
            }
          }
    } ```
````

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use one this libs

[react-native-image-base64](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-base64)
or
[rn-fetch-blob](https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob)

```
import RNFetchBlob from 'rn-fetch-blob';

 RNFetchBlob.fs
  .readFile(filePath, 'base64')
  .then((data) => {
    setdata(data);
  })
  .catch((err) => {});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [react-native-fs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs) library. It's better to decode the file path/uri.

```
import RNFS from 'react-native-fs';
...
const base64 = await RNFS.readFile(decodeURIComponent(filePath), 'base64');
...
```